# How do I use Protractor to loop through a set of elements and test if they are clickable

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor

I need to test if a list of buttons on the page are displayed and enabled First I gather all of the elements with elements.all

```
allEmployeeOptions = element.all(by.css('[role=option]'));
```

Then I attempted to use the .each function to loop through them and test if they are displayed (I will add isEnabled too).

```
   testAllOptionsClickable(){
    //this.actions.click();
    browser.sleep(3000);
    this.allEmployeeOptions.each(function(elm){
    expect(elm.isDisplayed).toBe(true);
    });
```

This doesn't seem to be working, I get "Expected function to be true" repeated 10 times for each element.

My best guess is that it is having trouble resolving the looping promise, but this is my first time writing a loop like this in Protractor. It's also possible .each is not the right approach and a for loop would be better.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`.each` is the right approach, I would not use a for loop to iterate over elements.  Your problem is just missing parenthesis, `isDisplayed()` is a function so you simply need to change your assertion to `expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);`

Also, for what it's worth I would add another assertion.  Being displayed does not mean an element is necessarily clickable, you should consider adding a check for [isEnabled()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isEnabled) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. But protractor has it's method to ckeck if an element is clickable.

```
example:


it('....xxxx.', function() {
    elems=$$('.items.item li'); // use your css locator
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    elems.each(async function(elem){
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elem), 5000);
    // perform other action 
    let elmtxt= await elem.getText();
    console.log("text: "+elmtxt);
    //expect(elem.isDisplayed()).toBe(true); /toBeTruthy();/
});
```